# Iterator for Hashset class

Tags: java

I have troubles implementing an Iterator for my TupleHashSet class.
The hashArr attribute stores the Hashsets for my Tuple (Pair) objects. The insert method inserts the Tuples according to the calculated HashCode.

The problem is that my iterator doesn't iterate through the entire HashArr if I insert something with the method.

My teacher told me a tip that my approach is wrong since the HashSet value aren't interested in order. However, I'm not sure what he means with that.

**TupleSet**

```
public class TupleSet<T, S> implements Iterable<Tuple<T, S>> {

    private final Tuple<T, S>[] hashArr;
    public static final int SS = 999;

    public TupleHashSet() {
        hashArr = new Tuple[SS];
    }

    @Override
    public java.util.Iterator<Tuple<T, S>> iterator() {
        return new Iterator(hashArr);
    }

    class Iterator implements java.util.Iterator<Tuple<T, S>> {
        private Tuple<T, S>[] array;
        private int index = 0;

        Iterator(Tuple<T, S>[] t) {
            this.array = t;
        }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
            for (int i = index; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                if (array[i] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

    @Override
    public Tuple<T, S> next() {
            for (int i = index; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                if (hashArr[i] != null) {
                    index = i + 1;
                    return hashArr[i];
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

    }
```

Comment: I'm curious about something.  Set's are unordered data structures.  Yet you have quite a few methods that imply order which makes no sense.  You might want to implement the Set interface as part of your class (or at least take a look at it).  For your "buckets" you may want to consider using a linked list to store the elements that hash to that bucket.  Imo, it is easier and eliminates the need to check for nulls during iteration.

Comment: I think the point of this exercise is to create a Set interface by myself. How can i iterate through this list without implementing any other methods and classes? Your idea will be appreciated

Comment: Well you haven't created an interface. An interface just defines the standard methods that should be required for all implementations of that type.  But it typically doesn't provide any implementations itself.  Just the method signatures.

Comment: You have an array of tuples - how do you deal with hash collisions? The way you handle those will influence your iterator…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer addresses your question about the iterator not returning all items.

The array index is never incremented, so it will always return the item at index `1`, which is `index + 1`. `index` must be incremented in the call to `next` before returning so that the next call starts at the subsequent element in the backing array.

Also, the backing array is not dense (meaning there could be empty slots at arbitrary positions, and that's OK), so the `next` function has to find the next valid entry, not just give up if the next entry is empty (i.e. `null`).

Try this instead:

```java
@Override
public Iterator<Tuple<T, S>> iterator() {
    Iterator<Tuple<T, S>> it = new Iterator<Tuple<T, S>>() {
        private int index = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            for (int i = index; i < SIZE; ++i) {
                if (hashArr[i] != null) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public Tuple<T, S> next() {
            for (int i = index; i < SIZE; ++i) 
                if (hashArr[i] != null) {
                    index = i + 1;
                    return hashArr[i];
                }
            }
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }

    };
    return it;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I have tried and modified it., but it still isn't functioning. 
My teacher told me a tip that my approach is wrong since the HashSet value aren't interested in order. 
However, I'm not sure what he means with that.

Comment: Should the iterator return the items in a certain order? If so, ordered by what? At any rate keeping an array ordered might better be a topic for a separate question. When you say it "isn't functioning", what precisely is the problem? What is the expected output, what is the actual output are you getting for which input?

Comment: We have a JUnit Test online which displays:
Your iterator does not run on foreach despite inserted objects. ==> expected: <true> but was: <false>

Comment: Then I recommend you write some tests yourself. Either formally, if you are familiar with something like JUnit, or informally, by writing a main method, inserting elements, printing the values returned by the iterator and convince yourself that you're getting what _you_ expect. From there you can work on getting the results that your teacher expects.

Comment: Thank you! I will try writing some tests myself!

Comment: your method worked, thanks a lot. I had to rewrite the iterable interface

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible solution.

```
public boolean hasNext() {
  for(; index < SIZE && hashArr[index] == null; index++);
  return index < SIZE;
}
```